# Not exactly a progression bar

Tags: discord.py

**I wanna make something like the image given below, I want to make a bar like that using emojis and show the percentage using discord.py**

*I don't know what to use for this. like what type of package or should i make those emojis. If I make those custom emojis then I have to make that in every server and I didn't wanna do that.*

[The progression bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7NNK.png)

Comment: Do you know which bot this is? If you can find the source, you can see how they're doing it.

Comment: Please do not post links as part of your question. If your link breaks the question is useless

Answer (score 0):

You can use emojis to create such a progression bar.

Using any image editor program, make 6 types of emojis: start empty, end empty, start full, end full, inside empty, inside full. The start will go on the beginning, the end will go on the end of the progress bar. You can put 1 start, 8 insides and 1 end to represent 100% divided into 10 pieces, so 1 emoji will represent 10%.

Add those 6 emojis to a private server - one where the bot is invited in - and in the chat box, type the emojis name (e.x. :insideempty:) and select it from the emoji selection menu. Then, go to the beginning of the emoji's name, and add a backslash `\`, and repeat this with all 6 of the emojis. When you send it, you will see a lot of long numbers and emojis, such as `<:insideempty:123456789>` - this is the emoji's ID, which you will use in the code. You can also use a basic discord emoji, like  (`:blue_square:`), but if you want a progress bar that looks exactly like the image you attached, you should use custom emojis.

Then, you can use a 3rd-party library, such as [progressbar2](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/) to make a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

I made one with easy_pil:

```
from easy_pil import *
@bot.hybrid_command(name="level_progress")
async def level_progress(ctx:commands.Context):
    xp = 0
    progress = create_level_progress(xp)
    file = discord.File(fp=progress.image_bytes, filename="LevelProgress.png")
    message = await ctx.send("**Not too epic progress bar**")

    for i in range(1, 11):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        xp += 10
        await message.remove_attachments(file)
        progress = create_level_progress(xp)
        file = discord.File(fp=progress.image_bytes, filename="LevelProgress.png")
        await message.add_files(file)

def create_level_progress(xp):
    background = Editor(Canvas((400, 25), color="#141414"))
    background.rectangle((0, 0), width=400, height=25, color="#FFFFFF", radius=10)
    background.bar((0, 0), max_width=400, height=25, percentage=xp, color="#14bed8", radius=10)
    return background
```

This will generate a "progress/loading bar" and will edit the attachment of the  image to create a "loading effect".